# Formula disappearing when I exit the Google Sheets app?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a value in `G3` and a value in `H3`. In `I3` I have the following formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(G2:G&"."&H2:H)
```

(Note that the formula and the problem below is in multiple rows below)

to show the values in `G3` and `H3` together as a decimalised value. I used the array formula as I needed a way to insert new rows and maintain the formula in the I column as I want new information to be at the top. All was working fine but I've entered the spreadsheet this morning to find the correct values in the I column but without the formula there (except in row 2 which is blank and used as a divider between headers and info).

Any ideas as to why this has happened, please?

Comment: can you share that sheet?

Comment: Never mind, it appears that the formula still works even though it doesn't show in the fx box when I click on the relevant cell. Should have tested it before posting on here, sorry!

Comment: Hey, who hasn't had that happen! Just reading [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question). You may want to think about whether you want this question to stay in the system.